# HTML JS Carousel Slider that doesn't slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

OK, I currently have an HTML carousel slider with some JS involved.

In the interests is not only keeping what is left of my sanity in check (I know, "sanity" right? Remined me what that is again?) but also to keep from picking my computer up and throwing it against the wall repeatedly, can any look at the code below and tell me why I cannot get the slides to - well - slide.

Thank you

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.content{
    height: 400px;
    width: 750px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content .images{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.images div{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.btm-sliders{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    display: flex;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

.btm-sliders span{
    height: 15px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 4px solid red;
    margin: 0 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content .slide{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 45px;
    /*height: 45px;*/
    border: 2px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

.content .slide:hover{
    background-color:#0d0155;
}

.slide span{
    font-size: 35px;
    color: red;
    line-height: 41px;
    
}

.content .right{
    right: 5px;
}

.content .left{
    left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="styles-carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ad445e50d3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="images">
            <div class="">You</div>
            <div class="">should</div>
            <div class="">see</div>
            <div class="">this</div>
            <div class="">one at a time</div>
        </div>
        <div onClick = "side_slide(-1)" class="slide left">
            <span class="fas fa-angle-left"></span>
        </div>
        <div onClick = "side_slide(1)" class="slide right">
            <span  class="fas fa-angle-right"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="btm-sliders">
            <span onClick = "btm_slide(1)"></span>
            <span onClick = "btm_slide(2)"></span>
            <span onClick = "btm_slide(3)"></span>
            <span onClick = "btm_slide(4)"></span>
            <span onClick = "btm_slide(5)"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var indexValue = 1;
        showDiv(indexValue);
        function btm_slide(e){showDiv(indexValue = e);}
        function side_slide(e){showDiv(indexValue += e);}
        function showImg(e){
            var i;
            const Div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
            const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.btm-sliders span');
            if(e > Div.length){indexValue = 1}
            if(e < 1){indexValue = Div.length}
            for(i = 0; i < div.length; i++){
                
                Div[i].style.display = "none";
                
            }
            
            for(i = 0; i< Div.length; i++){
                
                sliders[i].style.background = "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)";
            }
            
            Div[indexValue-1].style.display = "block";
            
            sliders[indexValue-1].style.background= "white";
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them. Always read the error. `"Uncaught ReferenceError: Div is not defined"` - you're referencing a variable with capital D `Div`, but your variable is named lowercase  `div`.

Comment: I actually did get into the habit of reading errors, I changed this to a lower case 'd' and guess what, still the same result....

Comment: Guess what, you're still ignoring errors

Comment: `"message": "ReferenceError: showDiv is not defined",`

Comment: Ohh guess what, I defined the ''ShowDiv', and guess what.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Updated your code

```js
 
        var indexValue = 1;
        showDiv(indexValue);
        function btm_slide(e){showDiv(indexValue = e);}
        function side_slide(e){showDiv(indexValue += e);}
        function showDiv(e){
            let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (e > slides.length) {indexValue = 1}    
  if (e < 1) {indexValue = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[indexValue-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[indexValue-1].className += " active";
        }
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.content{
    height: 400px;
    width: 750px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content .images{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.images div{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.btm-sliders{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    display: flex;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

.btm-sliders span{
    height: 15px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 4px solid red;
    margin: 0 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content .slide{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 45px;
    /*height: 45px;*/
    border: 2px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

.content .slide:hover{
    background-color:#0d0155;
}

.slide span{
    font-size: 35px;
    color: red;
    line-height: 41px;
    
}

.content .right{
    right: 5px;
}

.content .left{
    left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="styles-carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ad445e50d3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="images">
            <div class="mySlides">You</div>
            <div class="mySlides">should</div>
            <div class="mySlides">see</div>
            <div class="mySlides">this</div>
            <div class="mySlides">one at a time</div>
        </div>
        <div onClick = "side_slide(-1)" class="slide left">
            <span class="fas fa-angle-left"></span>
        </div>
        <div onClick = "side_slide(1)" class="slide right">
            <span  class="fas fa-angle-right"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="btm-sliders">
            <span class="dot" onClick = "btm_slide(1)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onClick = "btm_slide(2)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onClick = "btm_slide(3)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onClick = "btm_slide(4)"></span>
            <span class="dot" onClick = "btm_slide(5)"></span>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you  so that someone else doesn't put effort.

Comment: Sorry Adesh, answer accepted.